# lighttpd rewrite in magento

Tags: rewrite, lighttpd, 301-redirect

I'm currently using below code in `lighttpd.conf` to redirect `http` to `https`.

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
        url.redirect = (".*" => "https://%0$0")
    }
}
```

However, using above either `lighttpd` or `Magento` add `/index.php/ to the end. So http://example.com redirect to https://example.com/index.php/

Can the above code cause this and if not, is there anyway to make it disappear using some additonal rewrites?

Answer (score 0):

```
url.rewrite-once = (
                        "^(/(media|skin|js|downloader|app)/.*)$" => "$0",
                        "^/(.*\.php)" => "$0",
                        ".*\?(.*)" => "/index.php?$1",
                        "^/(.*)" => "/index.php/$1"
                        )

                static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )
                url.access-deny = ( "~", ".inc", ".conf", ".bak", ".xml", ".phtml", ".log", ".ini", "/var" )
```

Use these.